# Clone with related -- PricebookEntryId (pricebook entry is in a different pricebook than the one assigned to the opportunity): [PricebookEntryId]

Tags: opportunity, opportunity-lineitem, pricebook, pricebookentry

I am getting this issue PricebookEntryId (pricebook entry is in a different pricebook than the one assigned to the opportunity): [PricebookEntryId]

when ever I tried to clone an opportunity with related records.

[image]

If I get this error in Apex then I can think that the issue is with my code but getting this error during standard salesforce clone itself

The Account currency code is in HKD. and we are having only standard price book and not any custom price book

This issue is happening only in PROD. If we move the same record to partial sandbox and if we test there things are working fine with out any issue

Comment: Certainly odd that it's happening with the standard clone button. About the only thing I can think of is that it's possible to experience weird things if you have features like multicurrency turned on.

Comment: @DerekF Yes Multi currency is turned on but its got enabled in sandbox also and things are looking good in sand box

Comment: you say `account currency code` but the relevant currencycode is in Opportunity. Typo?

Comment: @cropredy Opportunity Currency code and PriceBook currency code is in USD but account currency code is in HKD